# Approximation of a polynomial with fractional power

Tags: polynomials, approximation

I have a polynomial I need to find the roots of, the major difficulty is that this polynomial has fractional exponents. I have made an approximation and I would like to have some idea of the error I would have to deal with. (if there is a better way of doing this I am all ears)

The original polynomial is $p(x)=a x^{2.56}+bx^{1.78}+cx+d = 0$

First, I make an approximation polynomial $p_2(x)=a x^{2.5}+bx^{1.75}+cx+d \approx  p(x)$

Then I let $\alpha = x^{.25}$, giving me

$p_2(\alpha)=a \alpha^{10}+b\alpha^{7}+c\alpha^4+d$

Which I solve the zeros of using the Jenkins–Traub algorithm.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help because I don't know much about this, but once you have the zero of $p_2$, you could use the Newton-Raphson method with $p$ using the zero of $p_2$ as your initial guess in order to make your answer more accurate.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: I will look to you "temple keeper", but using proper names is of major importance in mathematics : the word polynomial is restricted to a sum of monomials that have the form $ax^n$  with $a$ real or complex and  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $n$ has to be an **integer exponent** (and not "coefficient").

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually I caught the term "coefficient" in the title but missed it in the first paragraph. How would you suggest replacing the word polynomial in a way that gets the point across?

Comment: I dont know any name for such an entity. Now, let me turn into a positive guy : why would you intend to approximate your exponents prior to find a convergent algorithm ? Do you have a sort of limitation on the computation power ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, it has to mind a solution in less than a millisecond. But more importantly, I made the approximation so that a real polynomial with integer exponents could be constructed. If there is a better way of numerically solving the original equation I would love to see it... but how many solutions would there even be for $a x^{2.56}+bx^{1.78}+cx+d = 0$?

Comment: Does finding the zeros even make sense? (by the way, this comes from a heat transfer engineering problem, I need to find the inverse of an equation to get a thermodynamic property in terms of another... it may be that taking the inverse makes the equation no longer make sense)

Comment: Several questions: What can be said about the location of coefficients in the complex plane? Are they real or complex numbers? If real, is there any information about the sign of the coefficients? Do you have to solve more than one equations at a time or do you have multiple equations which can be solved concurrently? Are $a$, $b$, $c$ constant, so that $d$ is the only variable or do they also vary?

Comment: @CarlChristian All coefficients are real. I need to find a solution for arbitrary coefficients, however I can provide their signs. $a$, $c$, and $d$ are negative, and $b$ is positive.

Comment: @CarlChristian I don't understand the question about multiple equations. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The question speaks to the amount of parallelism in the problem. Suppose you have simultaneous $m$ equations given by $(a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i)$ where $i=1,2\dotsc,m$, then we might solve the equations in groups of size $p$, where $p$ is your vector length using the SIMD instruction set or similar. At the opposite end of the scale we have the case where $m=1$ and parallelism is much more difficult to find and exploit.

Comment: @CarlChristian No such luck $m=1$ for sure. We may call it more than once, but you can't say it is a set of coupled equations.

Comment: I expanded my answer stressing the need for you to check the two exponents and I added a paragraph on the merits of rewriting $f$ as a polynomial of another variable than x.

Comment: It struck me that a better title would be "Finding the zeros of a weighted sum of rational powers of x". I can not find a tag for "nonlinear equation", but there is a tag called "roots" which covers this question. The tag "nonlinear systems" is not appropriate because we only have one equation/variable. I am tagging @JeanMarie to get third party input.

Comment: One one side, up to a change of variable, for example $x=X^{100}$, you would have a polynomial in (capital) $X$. Therefore, saying "polynomial in variable $x^{0.01}$ would be correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given the equation the nonlinear equation $f(x) = 0$ where $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = a x^p + bx^q + cx + d, \quad p = 2.56, \quad q=1.78
\end{equation}
It is known that $a, c, d$ are (strictly) negative and that $b$ is (strictly) positive. We first consider the question of the existence of solutions. It is clear that $f$ is continuous. We have $f(0) = d < 0$. Since
\begin{equation}
f(x) \rightarrow -\infty, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \ge 0
\end{equation}
we cannot immediately conclude if $f$ has a zero. We therefore seek to determine the range of $f$ in the standard manner. We have
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = apx^{p-1} + bq x^{q-1} + c = (2.56) a x^{1.56} +  (1.78)b x^{0.78} + c
\end{equation}
The fact that 
\begin{equation}
1.56 = 2 \cdot 0.78
\end{equation}
is hardly a coincidence and it is worth investigating which property of the original problem gave rise to this.

It is vital that you check that this is equality is true, i.e. that $p$ and $q$ are exact and not the result of rounding.

With the substitution 
\begin{equation}
y = x^{0.78}
\end{equation}
it is clear that $f'(x)=0$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
(2.56) a y^2 + (1.78)b y + c = 0.
\end{equation}
Given specific values of $a, b$ and $c$ it is (almost) trivial to determine if $f'$ has any zeros or not, but I urge you to consult Higham's book *"Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms"* if you have never considered catastrophic cancellation in this setting before. The stable solution of quadratic equations is discussed in either Chapter 1 or Chapter 2.

Solve the equation $f'(x)=0$ will allow you to break the interval $[0,\infty)$ into subintervals where $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. By evaluating $f$ at the break points, i.e the roots of $f'$ you will be able to detect any sign changes. By continuity, this will identify intervals which contain exactly one root.

For the sake of robustness I would recommend using the bisection algorithm. When speed is of essence, I always recommend a hybrid between the bisection algorithm and the secant method. In this manner you can have both the rapid convergence of the secant method and the safety of the bisection algorithm.

If this is part of a "serious" code, which will run billions of times or more and you need to ensure that it works subject to the limitations of floating point arithmetic, then do not hesitate to contact me via email. I can not make any promises, but it could be a fun problem.

I foresee no difficult in reaching a solution in less than a millisecond. I can not imagine that we would need more than a few thousand CPU cycles.

It is possible to view $f$ as a polynomial, but not in the variable $x$. Specifically, if $x=y^{50}$, then
\begin{equation}
f(x) = a x^{2.56} + bx^{1.78} + cx + d = a y^{128} + b y^{89} + y^{50} + c.
\end{equation}
This circumvents the need for any approximations, but I see no real advantage to this approach. We still have to determine the range of $f$ as well as the intervals which contain the root(s). Computing powers requires calls to the exponential and logarithm functions, so we are no better off with this form of $f$ than the original.